# Return multiple variables from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

In python, to return multiple variables, I can do --

```
def function_one(i):
    return int(i), int(i) * 2

value, duble_value = function_one(1)
```

How would I achieve this same result using javascript if functions may only return a single return value? (I assume using an array?)

Comment: Technically you're returning a *tuple* with two fields in it, which is still a single value.  I'm not familiar with Javascript, but if there's some sort of array or structure that can be used, then that'd be ideal.

Comment: If the two integers you're returning are prime numbers, you can return their product. :P

Comment: Makoto's comment is a very good one. **Python can only return *one value* as well.** JavaScript doesn't have a `tuple`-type so Objects (e.g. `dict`) or Arrays (e.g. `list`) can be used as a replacement. Also JavaScript doesn't have Sequence-unpacking (which makes the `x, y = tuple` possible in Python) so the decomposition must be done long-hand.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to either use an array or an object.

For example:

```
function test() {
    return {foo: "bar", baz: "bof"};
}

function test2() {
    return ["bar", "bof"];
}

var data = test();
foo = data.foo;
baz = data.baz;

data = test2();
foo = data[0];
baz = data[1];
```

Comment: Another option (but not as nice): `function test(ret) { ret.a = 42; ret.b = 43; }`

Comment: @AtesGoral That won't work when a "non-object" type is passed in (and will be a nasty exception if no params are supplied). It also makes me want to vomit a little.

Comment: @pst This assumes someone intentionally passes in an object. This method has its uses, especially when you're collecting a set of parameters into the same pool (object) from multiple sources.

Comment: What is the equivalent of a python dict, `{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}`, called in js?

Comment: @David542 Sometimes it is also called an associative array http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 3):

```
function foo(){
    return ["something","something else","something more","something further"];
}

let [a,b,c,d] = foo();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.