# Return two variables in one function

Tags: javascript, function

Consider the following code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m59Fg/)):

```
function test(){
   var h = 'Hello';
   var w = 'World';
   return (h, w);

}

var test = test();

alert(test);
```

On execution the function `test` only returns the second value (i.e. `'World'`). How do I make it return multiple values?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221445/return-multiple-variables-from-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot explicitly return two variables from a single function, but there are various ways you could concatenate the two variables in order to return them.

If you don't need to keep the variables separated, you could just concatenate them directly like this:

```
function test(){
  var h = 'Hello';
  var w = 'World';
  var hw = h+w 
  return (hw);
}
var test = test();
alert(test);
```

This would alert "HelloWorld". (If you wanted a space in there, you should use `var hw = h+" "+w` instead.

If you need to keep the two variables separated, you can place them into an array like so:

```
function test(){
  var h = "Hello";
  var w = "World";
  var hw=[h,w];
  return hw;
}
var test = test();
alert(test);
```

This allows the `h` and `w` values to still be accessed individually as `test[0]` and `test[1]`, respectively. However, alert(test) here will display "Hello,World" because of the way alert() handles arrays (that is, it prints a comma-separated list of each element in the array sequentially). If you wanted to produce the same output as your example code, you would need use something like `join()`. `join()` will construct a string from an array, it takes one argument which serves as a separator between the elements. To reproduce the two alerts from my first example, you would need to use `alert(test.join(""))` and `alert(test.join(" ")`, respectively.

My example could be shortened slightly by skipping the creation of the `hw` variable and just returning an array directly. In that case, test() would look like this:

```
function test(){
  var h="Hello";
  var w="World";
  return [h, w];
}
```

This could also be done as an object with `return { h : h, w : w };`, in which case you would access the individual variables as test.h and test.w, respectively.

Answer (score 19):

```
function test(){ 
  var h = 'Hello'; 
  var w = 'World'; 
  return {h:h,w:w}
}

var test = test();

alert(test.h);
alert(test.w);
```

one simple way to do is to return Object containing multiple key value pairs.

Comment: What if you had arguments inside the function parameters, how would this be written?

Answer (score 13):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates each operand and then returns the value of the last one.

You'd need to either return an array:

```
return [h, w];
```

...or an object:

```
return { h : h, w : w };
```

Which you'd then use as:

```
var test = test();
alert(test[0]); // "hello" - in the case of the array version
```

...or:

```
var test = test();
alert(test.w); // "world" in the case of the object version
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return an array or a new object.