# Mini-Max Sum - Return Two (or More) Spaced Numbers With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6, return

I realize that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738207/return-two-variables-in-one-function) has been asked before.

But as per [this coding challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen), I need to return the sum of the "min array" (smallest 4 numbers) and "max array" (largest 4 numbers) on the same line as two **numbers** separated by a space. Not as an array, string, or object.

> Output Format
>
> Print two space-separated long integers denoting the respective minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. (The output can be greater than a 32 bit integer.)

I have:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let smallest = arr.slice(0, -1);
  let largest = arr.slice(1, arr.length);
  let first = Number(smallest.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  let second = Number(largest.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  
  return first + " " + second;
}
```

And when I return `first` and `second`, they return as strings instead of numbers, I'm assuming that this is because I've added the `+ " " +` in-between them.

So then how do I return them as **numbers** with a **space** in-between?

I also tried `return Number(first) + " " + Number(second);` but it doesn't seem to matter, they still return as a string.

Similarly, storing the sums in an object:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let smallest = arr.slice(0, -1);
  let largest = arr.slice(1, arr.length);
  let first = Number(smallest.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  let second = Number(largest.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  let object = {first, second};
  return Object.values(object);
}
```

also returned the values as an array.

Comment: `10 14` is a string. That's it. There's nothing you can do to change that. Period.

Comment: Okay. Know why my code is failing on HackerRank then? https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `return` them - if you look at the testing code:

```
miniMaxSum(arr);
```

It doesn't log the result - just runs your code. Logging the result instead works perfectly:

```
console.log(first + " " + second);
```

Comment: Oh - correct, it does in fact say "_print_ the respective minimum and maximum values" in the instructions. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No problem @HappyHands31, always glad to help.